# SQL Server parse XML column to get a column value if other column value equals certain value

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery, shred

In SQL Server 2014 a table with a `CustomColumns` column that contains XML data with the following structure:

```
<CustomColumnsCollection>
  <CustomColumn>
    <Name>Brand</Name>
    <DataType>0</DataType>
    <Value>Duprim</Value>
  </CustomColumn>
  <CustomColumn>
    <Name>LabelGroup</Name>
    <DataType>0</DataType>
    <Value />
  </CustomColumn>
...
</CustomColumnsCollection>
```

I want to get value of column `Value` where column `Name` equals, i.e. 'Brand' (the following code is a part of bigger query, which I saved as `VIEW`):

```
MAX(DISTINCT PR.CustomColumns.value('(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn/Name="Brand"/Value)[0]', 'varchar(max)')) AS Brand
```

In this case I would like it to return 'Duprim'. How is this achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another method by using XPath predicate.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, CustomColumns XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (CustomColumns)
VALUES
(N'<CustomColumnsCollection>
    <CustomColumn>
        <Name>Brand</Name>
        <DataType>0</DataType>
        <Value>Duprim</Value>
    </CustomColumn>
    <CustomColumn>
        <Name>LabelGroup</Name>
        <DataType>0</DataType>
        <Value/>
    </CustomColumn>
</CustomColumnsCollection>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @param VARCHAR(30) = 'Brand';

SELECT  ID
    , c.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [Value]
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY CustomColumns.nodes('/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn[(Name/text())[1] eq sql:variable("@param")]') AS t(c);

-- hard-coded value
SELECT  ID
    , c.value('(Value/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [Value]
FROM @tbl
    CROSS APPLY CustomColumns.nodes('/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn[(Name/text())[1] eq "Brand"]') AS t(c);
```

> Output

```
+----+--------+
| ID | Value  |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Duprim |
+----+--------+
```

To help you with the view that is consumed by the MS Excel.
It would be great if you could provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in #1 above.

> SQL for Excel

```
SELECT ID
    , CustomColumns.value('(/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn[(Name/text())[1] eq "Brand"]/Value/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)') AS [Value]
FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but in this instance I'm using views and cannot declare variables, as far as I know...

Comment: @Elen. In such case you can use just a hard-coded value. I updated the answer.

Comment: thanks @Yizhak, perhaps I can just use Excel to parse it then, not sure how to `hard code it`

Comment: I see what you did there. That would work for me, however when I applied it to my query as `MAX(DISTINCT PR.CustomColumns.nodes('/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn[(Name/text())[1] eq "Brand"]')) AS Spec0,` SQL server gives me error `nodes is not valid function`... sorry I'm new to parsing XML within sql queries....

Comment: @Elen, if allowed you might switch from the VIEW to an *inline* function. Such a function will accept your input as parameter and will allow for the code in this answer using `sql:variable()`. Within Excel you can pass the needed value into the function easily.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT
    xc.value('(Value)[1]', 'varchar(50)') 
FROM
    PR
CROSS APPLY
    PR.CustomColumns.nodes('/CustomColumnsCollection/CustomColumn') AS XT(XC)
WHERE   
    xc.value('(Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)') = 'Brand'
```

The  `.nodes()` returns a list of XML fragments, each representing a `<CustomColumn>` node. Select the one with the `Name` value of `Brand` in the `WHERE` clause, and get the value of `Value` for that XML node

Comment: I ran this as subquery with `FROM dbo.Products as PR`, but it returned nothing....